Trying to finish scrape specific data from websites for my Solr search engine for my Django project
I am trying to finish the backend (Django) of my Solr search engine. I defined my fields in search_indexes.py, created my Solr core, configured my schema.xml and rebuilt my index.
A little backstory to my search engine. The vertical search engine will be focused on homeowners searching for local arborists (tree services) by putting in queries.
The documents with the fields I have created and indexed are company name, types of services, reviews etc…. So in order for me to finish the search engine, I need to scrape some data from arborist websites, that is company names, reviews, types of service.
From my basic understanding of web scraping/indexing, I have to follow these steps to accomplish this. Send GET requests to url’s -- parsing the raw HTML data  with BeautifulSoup to find elements/tags that contains the desired data -- save it in a JSON file -- indexing via Solr.
The company name is inside meta_tag = soup.find('meta', attrs={'name': 'description'}), reviews is inside <script type="application/ld+json"> and types of services is inside <script type="application/ld+json"> of the website HTML/JSON structure.
Now I have created the files in my Django project: scrape.py, parser.py, save_json.py and solr_index.py to perform these four tasks. So I would have to split the web scraping/parsing code into these files because I expect to scrape a lot more websites.
Anyway, onto my first issue. When I try and run the program for scrape.py, I get the following output Company name not found. Here is my scrape.py code. PS I'm using IntelliJ and on Windows
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.peaktreeco.com/"

response = requests.get(url)

data = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

meta_tag = soup.find('meta', attrs={'name': 'description'})

if meta_tag:
    description = meta_tag.get('content')
    print(f"Company name: {description}")


else:
    print(f"Company name not found")

It is supposed to be printing the company from the website and it isn’t.
The second problem I have, is regarding the rest of the code for the four steps I mentioned earlier. I want to know the remaining code to scrape the website(s), parse them, save to JSON and index them via Solr and how to split them into the four files so that my code is organized as I plan to scrape websites for arborists in every state of the U.S.
I am close to finishing this search and web scraping is the last task for my Django project with the exception of implementing DRF to connect my frontend (Vuejs) to the backend. I apologize for the long confusing response, here is the url for the website: https://www.peaktreeco.com/. Here is my schema.xml
    <field name="text" type="edge_ngram" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    
    <field name="company_name" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    
    <field name="company_city" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    
    <field name="company_state" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    
    <field name="company_price" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />

    <field name="experience" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    
    <field name="one_star" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    
    <field name="two_stars" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    
    <field name="three_stars" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    
    <field name="four_stars" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    
    <field name="five_stars" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    
    <field name="review_by_homeowner" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    
    <field name="tree_pruning" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    
    <field name="tree_removal" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    
    <field name="tree_planting" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    
    <field name="pesticide_applications" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    
    <field name="soil_management" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    
    <field name="tree_protection" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    
    <field name="tree_risk_management" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    
    <field name="tree_biology" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />

For scrape.py I parsed it with BeautifulSoup, and specified the content, i.e. company name in find() for meta_tag = soup.find('meta', attrs={'name': 'description'}) and it still isn't printing the company name.

you're not checking the result. response is probably not what you think it is. and even if it worked your company name would have been Over 16 years of experience. Find tree maintenance experts by calling Peak Tree Service for a free estimate.

Yeah I kind of figured and I know I worded this oddly in my post. But I was trying to extract the company name, Peak Tree Services, from the home page. When I inspected the elements of the website, I could only find the company name located in the description tag. I'm new to scraping and searching for data I need in Inspect. It is very difficult to filter through HTML of some websites. I can go back and edit my post, but what I meant ask, was how do I go about not only finding content in elements I need when they're nested in HTML and also how to properly parse the data I need with code

i'm not sure i understand your question(s) correctly. to be efficient in web-scraping you need to learn a bit of html. for example, to find the name of the company, going for the <title> tag may be simpler. but this is a problem way too broad for this site. and for the parsing you're already using beautifulsoup

Yes I agree, the  would be much simpler, but that would be in the  element and it's not there. I don't see any  when I inspect it

the title is where it should be. if you're having problems finding it, that's what beautifulsoup is for

Not' sure I follow. When you say the 'title is where it should be', do you mean that the title should be displayed on the public home page or be visibly located in the  element?

I decided to use Selenium. I'm currently using ChromeDriver for this. What is the latest version of ChromeDriver? I downloaded the latest version for Windows, but I'm getting this error message: ```   raise ValueError(f"The path is not a valid file: {path}")
ValueError: The path is not a valid file: path/to/chromedriver
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:```. PS I did add the path environmental variables
